# How to center image on mobile while doing it on desktop?

Tags: html, css

I am making a welcome page.

I have this image that seems centered on desktop.

**Desktop view:**

[image: desktop view]

However, the mobile view is horrible:

**Mobile view:**

[image: mobile view]

So.. we can see the image is not centered correctly. Now, I could fix this with hacks but hacks just rob me from learning the proper way to do it.

How can I center the image on mobile and desktop?

My code: (profits.png needs to be centered)

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    <h1 id='format' style="margin-top: 80px;">Welcome to example</h1>
    <p id='format' style="">follow up</p>
    <br>
    <h2 id="format"><i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Type your username <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type a username" style="font-size: 30px; text-align: center;" align="center">
    <button id="playbutton">Play</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2 id="format">Why us?</h2>
    <p id="format">comming soon</p>
    <br>
    <img src="images/profits.png" style="height: 165px; width: 650px;">
    <br>
    <p id="format">...</p>
    <p style="font-size: 150px;margin-top: 20px"><i class="fa fa-mobile" aria-hidden="true"></i> <i class="fa fa-desktop" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
</div>
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue';
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeue.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/Helvetica Neu Bold.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeue BlackCond.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeue Light.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeue Medium.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeue Thin.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueBd.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueHv.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueIt.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueLt.ttf');
        src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueMed.ttf');
    }

    #format{
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'
    }

    img{
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    button[id=playbutton]{
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 5px;

        height: 40px;
    }

    button:hover{
        background-color: darkgreen;
    }

    input:focus{
        outline: none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm assuming your profits.png has empty space on the left and right? You have to crop that.

Comment: @ShadowFiend Hm, yeah I think you are right.

Comment: @fastquak look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n75bv3qj/8/).

Comment: @ShadowFiend Yep. That worked. Thank you.

Comment: @fastquak welcome bro.

Comment: @ShadowFiend maybe put it as a answer so I can accept it

Comment: @fastquak I put  it now..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you have a fixed `width` in your `img`.. thats why your `margin: 0 auto;` is not working properly.. try changing it to percentage. or use `media queries` and set the width accordingly to the mobile size..

look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/n75bv3qj/8/)..

Answer (score 0):

You need use `data-at2x` for making Images as responsive in web site

**EXAMPLE**

```
<img src="img/logo 1.jpg" data-at2x="img/logo 2.jpg" alt>.
```

And also change image size, height, width according to Mobile screen.